# How to find out which cells are pulling data from another sheet

Tags: excel

I want to find out exactly which cells in my excel workbook are pulling data from another sheet inside the same workbook. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy way to do it if you don't have a lot of cells.

Click the cell you want to check, then go to "Formulas" -> "Trace Precedents". [you need to do it for each cell :(, so that's the disadvantage]. You might need to click several times for each cell.

Notice the difference in my picture. The cells in the range `B5:B13` has a formula linked to an external source (another worksheet or another workbook, shown as a little mini table), while the cell `B15` who has a blue arrow, is linked to cell `E14` on the same worksheet!

[image]

If you want to know which linkage (which source cell it's linked to), klick on the arrow and you should see this window;

[image]

If there are a massive amount of cells, I would give this VBA code a try:

[VBA to list all external links together with the cells containing the links](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/784326-vba-list-all-external-links-together-cells-containing-links.html)